# automatically add new list item if the Column has a value and adds a value 1 in calculated column

Tags: 2013, updatelistitems, calculated-column-formula

Hi is this possible in sharepoint 2013 formulas?

automatically add new list item if the Column has a value and adds a new value "1" in calculated column that's newly created

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done using formula, but you can do it using workflows. Create a SharePoint Designer workflow to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Never say Never...

If a Calculated Column [can hold Javascript](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/ActionDelete) to ***Delete*** an item, all it takes is changing it to JSOM code to ***Add*** an item

Drawback is this is only triggered when the Calculated Column is displayed in a View. But from a Form you end up in the default ListView page by default.

Another option is to use CSR (Client Side Rendering) code on the New and Edit Form which triggers the JSOM code, that way no Calculated Column is required.
You have a bit of a challenge here.. as the Item you are working on does not exist yet in the database.